# What is the process through which 2 electron spin can be entangled?

Tags: electrons, quantum-entanglement

What is the process in the lab through which 2 electrons are entangled,

[image]

ie. what are the steps to ensure that their spin/magnetic dipole will always give opposite results when measured later?

Answer (score -1):

An electron-positron pair is created when a photon strike and atomic nucleus:

[image]

or when two photons collide to create an electron-positron pair.

[image]

To ensure that charge and spin are both conserved, the electron and positron must therefore always have opposite spins. The spins are allowed to exist in an undetermined superposition state until either one is measured. The unmeasured one must now have opposite spin or else total spin in the system will not not conserved.

[image]

Electron positron pair creations are well observed in bubble chamber tracks.